# Pass GCP BigQuery Service Account json environment variable from lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, google-bigquery

I am writing a lambda to read data from BQ
to authenticate BQ we need to pass
`spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.credentials.location` to a json file location in order to authenticate via below code

```
       GoogleCredentials credentials;
       try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
           credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           log.error(e.toString());
           throw new CustomException(ErrorCode.EXTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
       }
```

but in aws lambda we can pass environment variables only
I tried copying all secrets of the file and put in environment  variables but still not able to authenticate.

Also I tried to
change this serviceAccountStream to byteArray but no luck
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream)